# QML: setting height of TextArea

Tags: qt, qml

When testing the following QML source with qmlscene, why does not the TextArea take the height of 300 pixels ? Supposedly, `height` is the parameter I have to use, and it is inherited from Item.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Pane {
    anchors.fill: parent
    Rectangle {
        id: new_dep_box
        anchors.fill: parent
        border.color: "gray"
        Column {
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            GridLayout {
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: parent.right
                columns: 2
                anchors.margins: 5
                Label {
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    text: "Parent:"
                }
                Label {
                    text: "28383"
                }
                Label {
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    text: "Recipient:"
                }
                TextField {
                    id: recipient
                    Layout.fillWidth: parent
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    text: "user@example.com"
                }
                Label {
                    text: "Title:"
                }
                TextField {
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    Layout.fillWidth: parent
                    text: "Title text"
                }
                Label {
                    text: "Description:"
                }
                TextArea {
                    height: 300
                    Layout.fillWidth: parent
                    text: "Sample"
                }
            }
            Row {
                Button {
                    text: " Cancel "
                }
                Button {
                    text: " Create "
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, why doesn't anchoring the 'Column' item makes it spread all the item evenly across the space ? I have been reading the docs but can't find any info on that.

Comment: Change the `height` property to either `Layout.preferredHeight: 300` or `implicitHeight: 300`.

Comment: @folibis , yeah, it works also with minimumHeight. Everything but the 'height' itself. So , I wonder what's wrong with that.

Comment: That's clearly described [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquicklayouts-overview.html#specifying-preferred-size)